# Is there any way to remove query posted on linux kernel mailing list?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

Is there any way to delete/remove mail posted on linux kernel mailing list ?

I have posted some information which should not be sent out, so please let me know
if there is any such possibility.

Comment: You may try to remove from archives, but rather **no** is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: Email the person who handles the mailing list and ask them to remove it.

Comment: This (longer answer) is unlikely to help. The linux kernel mailing list is delivered to thousands of people, all of whom will have an individual copy of the message. It is then publicly archived at several sites, each of which would have to be contacted for removal (even assuming they would agree to do so).